# How to make an HTTP request into an application within an opened session? (Django/Python)

Tags: python, django, authentication, request

Here's the deal: I've modified an open-source platform API to retrieve some information I needed (some basic info of registered users to create a user profile page). The user must be authenticated to use it.

I need to make a request to the API to retrieve that info, but how do I do it within that session? I'm using Python's **request** method into my page, but apparently it creates a new session, since I'm getting 401 errors whenever I use it.

Comment: Please show us some code and you need to pass the session cookie with your request if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Whenever I try to make a request through my Django application by r = requests.get("http://myhost/api/user/v1/profiles?type=student") I get 401, although I'm able to do directly through my browser when I'm logged in. I'm using the OpenedX platform, which uses OAuth2.

Comment: I'm aware that OAuth2 is cookie based, so maybe I just have to retrieve my  browser instance cookies